# Cannot close() stream in 'finally' clause, uninitialized variable/unhandled IOException [Java IO]

Tags: java, exception, file-io, io

So I have this method in a class file just trying to write a Book object to aPath (string).
However, it gives me 'Unhandled IOException', which I am not sure I understand why as it seems I have a catch clause for my try block.

So to fix this, I tried adding a 'throws' clause to my method, however once I did that, it said that the 'out' variable was not initialized.

Is there any way I can close my stream inside the finally clause?

```
    public void writeToFile(String aPath) {
    
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aPath));
            
            out.writeObject(this.book);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error writing to file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            out.close(); //unhandled IOException error :(
        }
    }
```

Comment: So catch it, but you should really be using try-with-resources here.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Like I said, if I do that, it then says uninitialized variable. I want to know why I cannot use out.close() in finally clause.

Comment: Err, because (1) you didn't initialize it, and (2) you didn't catch the `IOException` it can throw, just as the error messages say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) will handle the problem of uninitialized resources:

```
public void writeToFile(String aPath) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream out = 
             new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aPath))) {
        out.writeObject(this.book);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing to file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

According to the JLS, an `IOException` thrown by the `writeObject` call, OR by the implicit `close()` of the resource will be caught in that handler.

It is so elegant ...

---

Regarding, your attempt:

> I want to know why I cannot use out.close() in finally clause.

Because `out` has not necessarily been initialized.  For example, if the `IOException` was thrown in `new FileOutputStream(...)`, `out` won't have been initialized.  To get it to work using an explicit `finally`, you would need to do something like this:

```
public void writeToFile(String aPath) {
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aPath));
        out.writeObject(this.book);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening or writing to file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error closing file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you asked .... the exception handling / squashing is probably a bad idea:

- The caller gets no indication file write has failed.  It will continue executing as if nothing happened.
- A stacktrace should not normally be written to stdout.  If it is relevant, the stacktrace should be logged:

  - If this is an end-user application, showing stacktraces to users is nasty.  What they need is an informative error message.  Separately logging the exception / stacktrace to a log file *may* be useful for the sysadmin who installed / configured the software, or the programmer who wrote it.
  - If this is a service, then stuff written to standard output may be lost.  Real errors should be logged.  Things that are (maybe) due to bad user input should (maybe) not be logged.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, isn't this just  what I wrote but without the finally clause? I thought you need to close the stream. Do I not need to?

Comment: Actually, no it isn't.  Read it carefully.  You also need to do some reading about [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).  What it is doing is to add an implicit `finally` to manage the closing of the resource ... at the appropriate point.

Comment: Thank you, I have read the link you provided. From what I understand, with the try-with-resources syntax: try() {} catch{}, we can declare + initialize the streams inside the try(), execute what we need in the curly brackets and catch exceptions from try{} and the implicit close() with catch{}. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mind expanding on what you mean when you noted that "the exception handling/squashing is probably a bad idea"? I am curious to know what could be wrong in the second piece of code you provided. Would this not be the way to implement it if we chose not to use try-with-resources?

Comment: More or less correct.  In fact the resource is implicitly closed before you get to the catch.

Comment: What's wrong with it?  Apart from the exception handling which I answered in the question update, the main problem is that it is 2 to 3 times as much code.  For the person coming after you to read / maintain

Comment: I see. One more thing I'd like to ask is regarding your statement "The caller gets no indication file write has failed. It will continue executing as if nothing happened.". But aren't we printing out "Error opening or writing to file" if it failed? Would that not count as indication?

Comment: The caller is the code that calls this method ... not the person who *might* be reading the stuff written you standard output.